# R Foreach Iterator - Walkforward

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, iterator

How can I create a "walkforward" iterator using the **iterators** package? How can an iterator be created where each `nextElem` returns a fixed moving window?

For example, let's say we have a 10x10 matrix. Each iterator element should be a groups of rows. The first element is rows 1:5, second is 2:6, 3:7, 4:8....etc

How can I turn x into a walkforward iterator:

```
x <- matrix(1:100, 10)
```

EDIT: To be clear, I would like to use the resulting iterator in a parallel **foreach** loop.

```
foreach(i = iter(x), .combine=rbind) %dopar% myFun(i)
```

Comment: Are you addressing this question directly to Steve Weston, the author (I think) of the **iterators** R package?

Comment: No I am not addressing directly to Steve Weston. Just sending a thanks since Steve has done great work with his packages and also answering many questions on here. I can remove it if you want.

Comment: Not sure about desired output, but would the following work for you? `library(zoo) ; indx <- as.data.frame(t(rollapply(seq_len(nrow(x)), 5, function(x) x))) ; lapply(indx,  function(y) x[y, ])`

Comment: Thanks David! I think putting the lapply result inside of the iter function will accomplish my goal. Will run and confirm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an iterator that returns overlapping sub-matrices as you describe, but that would use much more memory than is required. It would be better to use an iterator that returns the *indices* of those sub-matrices. Here's one way to do that:

```
iwalk <- function(n, m) {
  if (m > n)
    stop('m > n')
  it <- icount(n - m + 1)

  nextEl <- function() {
    i <- nextElem(it)
    c(i, i + m - 1)
  }

  obj <- list(nextElem=nextEl)
  class(obj) <- c('abstractiter', 'iter')
  obj
}
```

This function uses the `icount` function from the `iterators` package so that I don't have to worry about details such as throwing the "StopIteration" exception, for example. That's a technique that I describe in the ["Writing Custom Iterators" vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/iterators/vignettes/writing.pdf).

If you were using the `doMC` parallel backend, you could use this iterator as follows:

```
library(doMC)
nworkers <- 3
registerDoMC(nworkers)
x <- matrix(1:100, 10)
m <- 5
r1 <- foreach(ix=iwalk(nrow(x), m)) %dopar% {
  x[ix[1]:ix[2],, drop=FALSE]
}
```

This works nicely with `doMC` since each of the workers inherits the matrix `x`. However, if you're using `doParallel` with a cluster object or the `doMPI` backend, it would be nice to avoid exporting the entire matrix `x` to each of the workers. In that case, I would create an iterator function to send the overlapping sub-matrices of `x` to each of the workers, and then use `iwalk` to iterate over those sub-matrices:

```
ioverlap <- function(x, m, chunks) {
  if (m > nrow(x))
    stop('m > nrow(x)')
  i <- 1
  it <- idiv(nrow(x) - m + 1, chunks=chunks)

  nextEl <- function() {
    ntasks <- nextElem(it)
    ifirst <- i
    ilast <- i + ntasks + m - 2
    i <<- i + ntasks
    x[ifirst:ilast,, drop=FALSE]
  }

  obj <- list(nextElem=nextEl)
  class(obj) <- c('abstractiter', 'iter')
  obj
}

library(doParallel)
nworkers <- 3
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(nworkers)
registerDoParallel(cl)
x <- matrix(1:100, 10)
m <- 5
r2 <- foreach(y=ioverlap(x, m, nworkers), .combine='c',
              .packages=c('foreach', 'iterators')) %dopar% {
  foreach(iy=iwalk(nrow(y), m)) %do% {
    y[iy[1]:iy[2],, drop=FALSE]
  }
}
```

In this case I'm using `iwalk` on the workers, not the master, which is why the `iterators` package must be loaded by each of the workers.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated. I am using an doMPI cluster on a single physical machine with 62 cores. I would also like to avoid sending the full matrix to each of the workers. Will what you describe work using doMPI backend? One thing I like about doMPI and ForEach options.mpi is using chunkSize in to send multiple tasks to the workers - which I have observed an over 50% decrease in time with just that. So, very curious if the time will further decrease by not having to export the entire matrix.

Comment: Also, in the last line code above, where does y come from? How does it get defined? My guess is that foreach is doing some magic. :)

Comment: @EBW The doParallel example works just as well with doMPI since doMPI also doesn't use fork to start the workers. Also, there's no reason to use chunkSize with doMPI in this case, since effectively we're manually chunking.

Comment: @EBW `y` is just the iteration variable of the outer foreach loop which references the sub-matrices returned by the `ioverlap` iterator. There's no problem using those values in the body of the inner, sequential foreach loop. I don't think that qualifies as magic...

Comment: Thanks Steve! Also, I see now that y gets created in the parent foreach loop. I will use this method and report back.

Comment: I have implemented your suggestion and there is a nice speedup. Interestingly, when I compare your suggestion to using options.mpi chunksize of 6, the execution time is almost exactly identical! However, since I'm only using 1 physical server, would the fastest route be to use doMC instead? Would using doMC remove some overhead such as network overhead?

Comment: @EBW If you're using a single, non-Windows computer, then I would use the doMC version. It will probably be faster since the task inputs are tiny, and it's certainly simpler.

Comment: After running some tests, I have confirmed that doMC is about 15% faster than the doMPI (on a single physical server with 62 cores). Thanks so much for your help!